# Отсутствует перевод одной из строк в списке причин для "связи с нами"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, контактная-форма

Как видно на картинке, отсутствует перевод, о чём и сообщаю.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего капча сложилась в столбик? Хм.. У меня так же...

Comment: @Qwertiy капча неправильно отображается? Вот кнопка - точно [криво обрезалась](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366456/339911).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически отсутствуют переводы всего множества строк, связанных с этой причиной. Добавил переводы для тех, что заметил:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16588
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16618
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16587
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16617
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16635
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16580
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16634
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16632
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16623
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16593
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16643
- <s>https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16636 ([проблема в оригинальной строке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366455/339911), может потребовать повторного перевода)</s>

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.6.11.39480